# knockout js. foreach children of a child not working

Tags: javascript, foreach, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am having trouble iterating over my json data with knockout.
My view model looks like :

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.Summary = ko.observableArray();
    $.getJSON('some api url', function(result) {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(result, {}, self);
    });
}
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

My JSON data looks like :

```
{
Summary: {
    Details: [
        {
            Name: "Foo",
            Id: 1,
            Detail: "Some Data"
        },
        {
            Name: "Bar",
            Id: 2,
            Detail: "Another Data"
        }
    ],
    SummaryOverview: "BlahBlah",
    AnotherObject: [
        {
            Name: "My Name"
            AnotherChildObject: [
                {
                    name:"some name"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}
My question is do I iterate thru my data this way:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: Summary">             
    <div data-bind="text: Details.Detail"></div>
</div>
```

**OR**

```
<div data-bind: "foreach: Summary.Details">
    <div data-bind="text: Detail"></div>
</div>
```

How do I display the Detail?  The HTML above is not working for me.
Thank you very much!!

Comment: Check your foreach -- looks like you misspelled "Summary" as "Summarry"

Comment: Your data doesn't contain an array of anything, it's not even valid... so it shouldn't work at all.  What is it supposed to be?

Comment: Your JSON is not valid, and there are several possibilities how it can be interpreted. We do not know what you want to represent with it, so please provide us with valid JSON-Data, then we can show you how to modify your javascript.
And like Jeff Mercado said: There is no array in your JSON. If you want to use foreach, there has to be an array. Please correct it.
And as Disgone saif, your HTML uses the wrong name to access the data.

And as I say: Please put more effort in your questions and specifically your examples. If you do not value your problem high enough to be thorough, why should we?

Comment: i'm sorry, i was typing too fast and made some typos in the original post. here's my json:
`code`
{
 Summary: {
  Details: [
   {
    Name: "Foo",
    Id: 1,
    Detail: "Some Data"
   },
   {
    Name: "Bar",
    Id: 2,
    Detail: "Another Data"
   }
  ],
  SummaryOverview: "BlahBlah",
  AnotherObject: [
   {
    Name: "My Name"
    AnotherChildObject: [
     {
      name:"some name"
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
}`code`

Comment: I edited the original post with the correct JSON...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `ko.mapping` is that your observables will be replaced with new observables. To clarify, the `Summary`, which is an observableArray, will be replaced by a new observableArray by `ko.mapping`.

There are two ways to remedy this. The first alternative is to wait with the `applyBindings` until the real array has been created:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    // no need to set the array, it will be overwritten anyway
    // self.Summary = ko.observableArray();
}

var vm = new ViewModel();
$.getJSON('some api url', function(result) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(result, {}, vm);
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

Alternative 2 is to bootstrap the viewmodel with initial (empty) data. If you apply `ko.mapping` on an empty array, the next call to `ko.mapping` will update the existing array rather than overwrite it. Like so:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    var init = { Summary: [] };
    ko.mapping.fromJS(init, {}, self);

    $.getJSON('some api url', function(result) {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(result, {}, self);
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

I usually go with alternative 2. Alternative 1 will cause a delay before `ko.applyBindings` is called, which might cause some UI flicker (and unwanted elements may be visible, etc).

Comment: Hi Christoffer, thanks for your response.  I tried both solutions you offered but could not get it to work.  I think my HTML code is off.  How would you do the foreach data-bind?  thanks